# Issue with adding html template with js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ckeditor

I am trying to add my html website code from `data-prototype`:

```html
<div id="accordion" data-prototype='
<div class="card-body">
    <textarea id="solution_answers___name___content" name="solution[answers][__name__][content]" required="required"></textarea>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "/bundles/fosckeditor/";
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (CKEDITOR.instances["solution_answers___name___content"]) { 
            CKEDITOR.instances["solution_answers___name___content"].destroy(true); 
            delete CKEDITOR.instances["solution_answers___name___content"]; 
        }

    </script>
</div>'></div>
```

As you can see, there is also some `js` code from ckeditor.

When I try to add it with `jquery`:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#accordion');
let template = el.dataset.prototype;
let $root = $(el);

$root.append(template);
```

Everything works fine, I mean there is no erros in console.

When I try to add it with vanilla js:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#accordion');
let template = el.dataset.prototype;
const scriptEl = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(template);
el.append(scriptEl);
```

In dev console, I am getting error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined
```

If I execute the same script one more time, the error is gone, and everything works as expected.

Does someone know, why I am getting that error?

[Here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/ckeditor.js) is the content of `/bundles/fosckeditor/ckeditor.js`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is not about you trying to add this html code to your site. You should define CKEDITOR as a `const` `let` or `var` (I don't recomend the third) instead using OR and assign it to the window object.

```js
const CKEDITOR = //...
```

Comment: Ok, but why with jquery it works?